# Why is my system clock absurdly wrong after reboot?

Tags: linux, clock

So I'm using a CentOS 8 system (just installed CentOS 8 minimal to reproduce on, so my application can't be an issue).

If I turn off ntp, and set the time to several years ago, things are as expected. (This particular date is part of testing for our DST handling).

```
timedatectl set-ntp off
timedatectl set-time "2017-03-11 19:55:00"
timedatectl 
               Local time: Sat 2017-03-11 19:55:11 EST
           Universal time: Sun 2017-03-12 00:55:11 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2017-03-12 00:55:11
                Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

If I then reboot, the system time is now absurdly wrong (more than a year later). Note that the RTC is correct, it's just the system's idea of time that's off the rails.

```
reboot
timedatectl
               Local time: Fri 2018-06-22 07:13:26 EDT
           Universal time: Fri 2018-06-22 11:13:26 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2017-03-12 00:57:22
                Time zone: America/New_York (EDT, -0400)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Now at that point I got the idea that /etc/adjtime was involved and tried deleting it.

```
rm -f /etc/adjtime
reboot
ls -al /etc/adjtime
ls: cannot access '/etc/adjtime': No such file or directory
timedatectl
               Local time: Fri 2018-06-22 07:18:54 EDT
           Universal time: Fri 2018-06-22 11:18:54 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2017-03-12 01:02:50
                Time zone: America/New_York (EDT, -0400)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

No effect. RTC is still fine, system time is bogus.

I would like to know what is going on here and (if possible) how to make it stop. In the cases where we turn off ntp sync (our system operates without a network quite frequently), we need to know that our customers can at least set the TIME and have it do what they want.

Additional information:
This is running on real hardware (two completely different systems, in fact).

The C8 system was shut down after my original posting and I just rebooted it now, 2 days later. The RTC time has moved along as you'd expect, but the system time is back where it was on the previous tests, as if something has a 'minimum' time that it'll set, as opposed to some kind of offset.

```
timedatectl
               Local time: Fri 2018-06-22 07:12:46 EDT
           Universal time: Fri 2018-06-22 11:12:46 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2017-03-14 12:20:20
                Time zone: America/New_York (EDT, -0400)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: Check the motherboard battery?

Comment: Is this running on bare metal or in a virtual machine? If it's a VM, look for utilities that might try to keep the clock synchronized with the host.

Comment: Check the system logs (`/var/log/*`) for messages about the time (probably containing the word "time" or "clock").

Comment: First, RTC denote the Real TIme Clock. The fact RTC is in the correct TZ implies TZ hasn't changed - which read from a file - It doesn't imply the RTC is working. Second, in NTP there is  limit to how far it will adjust a clock. I would recommend setting the coorect time by hand, turning NTP so it starts at boot and rebooting. But if you have to take it down, change the battery on the mother board - batteries are cheap - don't guess. And It's not clear if set_ntp off just kills NTP or disables it.

Comment: System time is bogus because you set it to a bogus time. Consider setting it according to the RTC clock and then start the NTP daemon again. The fact that you don't have 24h network accessibility does not justify setting the time several years wrong. It would be better if you implemented some solution that correctly sets the time whenever the network is up, if that's not already what the default setup is doing.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I'm sorry, what part of what I wrote was unclear? The issue is that it doesn't match the RTC. If it matched the RTC there wouldn't be a problem. And, as stated, setting the clock to bizzare dates happened during testing.

Comment: @MichaelKohne It's unclear what you are testing. If it's a possible real-world scenario, then it shows that you possibly need a routine to reset the system clock to the RTC clock if it's accidentally set back 10 years. It's well known that NTP can't handle huge corrections, and since you don't have 100% network access, correcting the time with a `ntpdate` in an hourly cron job might be the best option.